# In javafx tableview cell convert to white cell if ram up to 1 Gb

Tags: javafx, tableview, heap-memory, ram

the problem is when I run my application for two hours and the ram up to 1Gb
the tablecell convert to white when the mouse move hover

link of youtube video show the tablecell convert to white when the mouse move hover

> https://youtu.be/lARJj80bkA8

I have write for each column `setCellFactory` and `setCellValueFactory`

```
initial heap size 512 MB
Max heap size 1024 MB
```

also test on

```
initial heap size 1024 MB
Max heap size 1536 MB
```

what do you think the problem?

---

***UPDATE 1#***

simple code for what I have doin

this app is read file for stock market

```
public class Stock implements Initializable {
    @FXML public TableView<RowModel> tbl;
    public ObservableList<RowModel> obsTbl;
    @FXML public TableColumn<RowModel, Number> tcDataClose;
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        obsTbl = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        tbl.setItems(obsTbl);
        
        tcDataClose.setCellValueFactory(cell -> cell.getValue().dataCloseProperty());
        
        tcDataClose.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<RowModel, Number>, TableCell<RowModel, Number>>() {
            @Override
            public TableCell<RowModel, Number> call(TableColumn<RowModel, Number> param) {
                return new TableCell<RowModel, Number>(){
                    @Override
                    protected void updateItem(Number item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        if(!empty && item != null){
                            setGraphic(null);
                            RowModel rowModel = getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex());
                            setText(MathTools.toPriceAsString(rowModel.getDataClose()));

                            if(rowModel.getDataClose() > rowModel.getM()){
                                this.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#007d00 ;");
                            }else if(rowModel.getDataClose() < rowModel.getM()){
                                this.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#b80000 ;");
                            }else{
                                this.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#323232 ;");
                            }
                        }else{
                            setGraphic(null);
                            setText(null);
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
        });
        
    }
}
```

every 5 secand after read stock markect files

```
tbl.refresh();
System.gc();
```

Comment: show us what you have done. I think there is a mistake

Comment: @Raw I have write simple code I hope this code help to understand the mistake

Comment: @Raw also every 5 second I read binarry file to get the leatest update of stock market, so the problem show when the ram up to 1 GB

Comment: @Abra (1)my app used between 800Mb and 1.2GB (2) I set -Xmx1536 Xms1024 (3)I dont have `OutOfMemoryError`

Comment: at the end, the only way to find the bottleneck is to profile your app - nothing we can do from here (particularly not with a random snippet of code vs. a [mcve])

Comment: that said, there are fishy points in your code/description - why don't you use the given item in the cell? why do you think you need table.refresh? Both sound like a suboptimal setup. Also, you don't reset the style in to nothing in the outer else and null the graphic always even though it never was not-null

Comment: You are passing `Number` to the data row. I do not see where you actually use the `Number` item in your cell factory. It looks like you are trying to query for data as things change. You probably need to pass the data instead of  `Number`. My guess is that you need to use `Timeline` to update that data periodically.